VLC player unable to start webcam in desktop: unable to open MRL
Ubuntu 24.04
VLC v.3.0.20
when I open VLC and click on Media > Open capture Device and select video camera and Video Device name /dev/video1 ; it gives error although i am able to open wewbcam using ffplay


Have you installed it from Software? Did you look into Settings, Apps, VLC and gave it permission?

I have installed uing App store but unable to find permission in anywhere

Have you contacted VLC support and asked them or looked into their forums?

Checking permission was needed. Using Settings --> Apps and then allow to use Camera.

now it works :)

Your answer applies to all snap apps. When in doubt about a snap always check Settings, Apps, your snap.
